# jquery datatables: columnFilter() is not a function error

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

i am using Data Tables with custom server side filtering, search and sorting... why is the columnFilter() returning an error "TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).columnFilter is not a function"

here is how i use columnFilter:

```js
var table = $('#item-table').DataTable({
    ajax: '<?= site_url("price_update"); ?>',
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    paging: true
}).columnFilter();
```

my code without the ".columnFilter()" works fine.

Comment: DataTable() or dataTable() ?

Comment: DataTable() with the upper case D

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You **must** use the "oldschool" `dataTable()` constructor when using `columnFilter`. Proof of concept :

**works not**, produces same error as in the question :
columnFilter with 1.10.x instantiated with `DataTable()` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/87kam74q/**

**works** :
columnFilter with 1.10.x instantiated with `dataTable()` -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LvL4vm8e**/

The reason is, that `columnFilter` assumes it is working the "old" jQuery object, not the new API object. Though, you can still access the new API through the `.api()` method, for example :

```js
var table = $('#example').dataTable();
table.api().search('test').draw();
```

---

If you not want to go through `table.api()` for using the new AP, and insists on using `DataTable()`, you can achieve the same by giving up the chaining :

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
$('#example').dataTable().columnFilter({
    sPlaceHolder : 'head:before',
    aoColumns: [ { type: "text"},
                 { type: "text"},
                 { type: "text"},
                 { type: "text"},
                 { type: "text"}
               ] 
});
```

fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/qbr01oya/**. This does not result in the dataTable being initialized twice (dataTables check for that).

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me.. then the only way to do this now with the non "oldschool" dataTable is to make an api for it at this moment?

Comment: @ChristianBurgos, yes - but if you will give up the dot chaining, you can do both. See updated answer.

Comment: is this applicable for serverside processing?

Comment: I used jquery-1.11.1.min.js, Just changed the $('#example').DataTable to $('#example').dataTable

It worked like a charm! Thanks.