# I am getting this $(...).dataTable(...).columnFilter is not a function

Tags: jquery, datatable

I want to start with I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26229855/jquery-datatables-columnfilter-is-not-a-function-error) and I am using the correct constructor.

I get this error when I am running my code:

> $(...).dataTable(...).columnFilter is not a function

html:

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="activeProjects">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Project Name</th>
            <th>Project Number</th>
            <th>Manager</th>
            <th>Architect</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var table =  $('#activeProjects').dataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "../api/Project/GetAll/",
                "dataSrc": ""
            },

            "columns": [
                { "data": "ProjectName" },
                { "data": "ProjectNumber" },
                { "data": "ProjectManager" },
                { "data": "ProjectArchitect" }
            ]
        }).columnFilter({
            aoColumns: [ { type: "text" },
                         { type: "text" },
                         { type: "text" },
                         { type: "text" }
            ]

        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Getting no problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/yhghcwc9/ (I had to remove your ajax stuff though)

Comment: @jcuenod So why would I be getting it?

Comment: Sure that this is the code that's running?

Comment: @jcuenod Yep, I am on that page and it is being loaded

Comment: Is the fiddle working?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see any difference in the fiddle and my code

Comment: Check the external resources in fiddle. The file: jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js should be added as well